# Laravel - Unable to send Email to webserver from website

Tags: php, laravel, email, pyrocms

I am trying to send a mail through my contact from and i am getting this error:

> Swift_TransportException (550) Expected response code 250 but got code
>   "550", with message "550-Your FROM address ( test@email.com ,
>   test@email.com ) must match your 550-authenticated email user (
>   email@example.ro ). Treating this as a spoofed 550 email. "

My .ENV config:

---

```
MAIL_HOST=mail.exemple.ro

MAIL_PORT=465

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

MAIL_PASSWORD=my pass

MAIL_USERNAME=email@exemple.ro

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

FROM_ADDRESS=email@exemple.ro
```

---

My Contoller:

```
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'firstName' => 'required',
        'lastName' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'services' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('en/404')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    $form = $request->all();
    $message->success('The message was successfully send!');

    Mail::send('email/contact-form', compact('form'), function ($email_message) use ($form) {

        $email_message->subject($form['services']);
        $email_message->from($form['email']);
        $email_message->to('email@example.ro');

    });
    return back();
}
```

If i try to write the input Email with email@exemple.ro i get no error but when i try to enter a gmail or other email i am getting the error above.

Please help!

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? That you can't send from a gmail address via a greenfab.ro server?

Comment: The problem is that i cant send a email via Contact Form from my website.

Comment: Even when using happy@greenfab.ro as email sender?

Comment: When i do that is working with happy@greenfab.ro entered in email input.I can't figure out where the problem is. I deleted and recreate the email in Cpanel and still no succes

Comment: Try to ctrl+f `validator` in `vendor/anomaly/streams-platform` folder recursively...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed your code here

Just replace code from

```
Mail::send('email/contact-form', compact('form'), function ($email_message) use ($form) {

    $email_message->subject($form['services']);
    $email_message->from($form['email']);
    $email_message->to('happy@greenfab.ro');

});
```

To this below one

```
Mail::send('email/contact-form', compact('form'), function ($email_message) use ($form) {

    $email_message->subject($form['services']);
    $email_message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'),$form['email']);
    $email_message->to(env('MAIL_USERNAME'));
});
```

You were messing code in **from** and **to**. As you can only enter email in **from** which can authenticate to your **MAIL_HOST** server on port **MAIL_PORT**, thats why you don't get any error when you enter your email address.

I hope this would help you.

Comment: I made a mistake. Sorry!

Now i don't recive any error messages and i don't get the email :(
i am geting the messeges on the mail i input in form :))

Comment: This code will mail from your account to the user's email. and i think it should work

Comment: When i change the code as you told me  i receive the information i input in the contact form on the email i enter in Email input not the happy@greenfab.ro

Comment: okay so You want to send mail from your account to user with his information he entered in form ?

Comment: I want to receive the information the person enter in contact form on this email happy@greenfab.ro

Comment: If i change the  code like this :

 $email_message->subject($form['services']);
            $email_message->from($form['email']);
            $email_message->to(env('MAIL_USERNAME'));

I receive the same error as above.

Comment: But you cant send mail from user's email as you have not his credentials and server details

Comment: You can send mail from your account only.

Comment: I have updated the answer try the new code and let me know if it works as per your requirement.

Comment: Is working! But, from who i received the email i want to see the user email not  happy@greenfab.ro

Comment: Is there any possibility for the real problem to be related to the Host web server?

Comment: No its not its about mail only i will get back to you in short time

Comment: Okay. Thank you! One more question. Maybe is because i try to send a mail with a html template and the server is not seeing the message as safe?

Comment: No thats not issue. I have checked and i found that now you can't change email, what you can change is alias name. So if you want to pretend that mail is sent from user's account you just need to change alias.

Comment: Okay. I manage to get it done with your code from above. Thank you very much!